# Como trocar o desenho SVG por uma imagem PNG após completar a animação?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde! Coloquei um desenho em SVG no meu site, e coloquei uma animação para quando o desenho estiver visível na tela, começar a animação do desenho se "completando", segue o código JS.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

   var svg4 = new Walkway({
    selector: '#Layer_1',
    duration: 3500,
    redrawOnFocus: true
   });

   $(window).on("scroll", function(){
      var el = $('#Layer_1');
      var eleHeight = el.outerHeight(); // altura do elemento
      var eleTopo = el.offset().top; // distancia do elemento ao topo do documento
      var scrlTopo = $(window).scrollTop(); // quanto foi rolada a janela
      var distance = eleTopo-scrlTopo; // distancia do elemento ao topo da janela
      var altJanela = window.innerHeight; // altura da janela
      if(distance <= altJanela-(eleHeight/2)) {
         svg4.draw(); // inicia a animação
      }
   });

  document.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
    svg.redraw();
    svg4.redraw();
  }, false);
});

/*
 * Walkway.js
 *
 * Copyright 2016, Connor Atherton - http://connoratherton.com/
 * Released under the MIT Licence
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 * Github: http://github.com/ConnorAtherton/Walkway
 */

// Export Walkway depending on environment (AMD, CommonJS or Browser global)
;(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    root.Walkway = factory();
  }
}(this, function factory(exports) {
  'use strict';

  /*
   * Shim for requestAnimationFrame on older browsers
   */

  var lastTime = 0;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame;

  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
        callback(currTime + timeToCall);
      }, timeToCall);

      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };
  }

  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  }

  /*
   * Easing Functions - inspired from http://gizma.com/easing/
   * only considering the t value for the range [0, 1] => [0, 1]
   *
   * Taken from https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
   */

  var EasingFunctions = {
    // no easing, no acceleration
    linear: function (t) { return t; },
    // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInQuad: function (t) { return t*t; },
      // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutQuad: function (t) { return t*(2-t); },
      // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutQuad: function (t) { return t<0.5 ? 2*t*t : -1+(4-2*t)*t; },
      // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInCubic: function (t) { return t*t*t; },
      // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutCubic: function (t) { return (--t)*t*t+1; },
      // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutCubic: function (t) { return t<0.5 ? 4*t*t*t : (t-1)*(2*t-2)*(2*t-2)+1; },
      // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInQuart: function (t) { return t*t*t*t; },
      // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutQuart: function (t) { return 1-(--t)*t*t*t; },
      // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutQuart: function (t) { return t<0.5 ? 8*t*t*t*t : 1-8*(--t)*t*t*t; },
      // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInQuint: function (t) { return t*t*t*t*t; },
      // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutQuint: function (t) { return 1+(--t)*t*t*t*t; },
      // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutQuint: function (t) { return t<0.5 ? 16*t*t*t*t*t : 1+16*(--t)*t*t*t*t; }
  };

  /*
   * Creates a selector used to select all element to animate
   * Currently only supports *path*, *line*, and *polyline* svg elements
   *
   * @param {string} selector The selector of the parent element
   * @returns {string} the complete selector
   * @private
   */

  function _createSelector(selector) {
    var supported = ['path', 'line', 'polyline'];
    var newSelector = supported.reduce(function(prev, curr){
      return prev + selector + ' ' + curr + ', ';
    }, '');
    // chop the last , from the string
    return newSelector.slice(0, -2);
  }

  /*
   * All Walkway instances present on the current page. This is needed for when
   * the tab loses focus and we need to force each animation to finish.
   */
  var _elements = [];
  var _instances = [];

  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (!document.hidden) {
      return;
    }

    for (var i = 0, instancesLen = _instances.length; i < instancesLen; i++) {
      _instances[i].cancel();
    }

    for (var j = 0, elementsLen = _elements.length; j < elementsLen; j++) {
      _elements[j].complete();
    }
  }, false);

  /*
   * Walkway constructor function
   * opts.selector is the only mandatory param and can be passed in alone
   * as a string
   *
   * @param {object} opts the configuration objects for the instance.
   * @returns {walkway}
   */

  function Walkway(opts) {
    if (!(this instanceof Walkway)) {
      return new Walkway(opts);
    }

    if (typeof opts === 'string') {
      opts = { selector: opts };
    }

    if (!opts.selector) {
      return this.error('A selector needs to be specified');
    }

    this.opts = opts;
    this.selector = opts.selector;
    this.duration = opts.duration || 500;
    this.easing = (typeof opts.easing === 'function') ?
      opts.easing :
      EasingFunctions[opts.easing] || EasingFunctions.easeInOutCubic;
    this.id = false;
    this.elements = this.getElements();
    this.callback = opts.callback;

    this.setInitialStyles();

    _elements = _elements.concat(this.elements);
    _instances.push(this);
  }

  Walkway.prototype = {
    constructor: Walkway,

    /*
     * Prints an error message to the console
     *
     * @param {string} message the message to be displayed
     * @returns {void}
     */
    error: function(message) {
      console.error('Walkway error: ' + message);
    },

    /*
     * Uses a pre-build selector to find and store elements to animate
     *
     * @returns {array} of Path instances
     */
    getElements: function() {
      var self = this;
      var selector = _createSelector(this.selector);
      var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      els = Array.prototype.slice.call(els);

      return els.map(function(el) {
        if(el.tagName === 'path') {
          return new Path(el, self.duration, self.easing);
        } else if (el.tagName === 'line') {
          return new Line(el, self.duration, self.easing);
        } else if(el.tagName === 'polyline') {
          return new Polyline(el, self.duration, self.easing);
        }
      });
    },

    /*
     * Sets initial styles on all elements to be animated
     *
     * @returns {void}
     */
    setInitialStyles: function() {
      this.elements.forEach(function(n) {
        n.el.style.strokeDasharray = n.length + ' ' + n.length;
        n.el.style.strokeDashoffset = n.length;
      });
    },

    /*
     * The general update loop for the animations.
     * Once individal paths are completed they are marked as such and
     * are not updated.
     *
     * @returns {void}
     */
    draw: function(callback) {
      var counter = this.elements.length;
      var allComplete = this.elements.filter(function(el) { return el.done; }).length === counter;
      var element = null;
      var done = false;

      // Overwrite existing callback passed in with options
      this.callback = callback || this.callback;

      if (allComplete) {
        if (this.callback && typeof(this.callback) === 'function') {
          this.callback();
        }

        this.cancel();
        return;
      }

      while (counter--) {
        element = this.elements[counter];
        done = element.update();

        if (done) {
          element.done = true;
        }
      }

      this.id = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this, callback));
    },

    cancel: function() {
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.id);
    },

    redraw: function() {
      this.cancel();

      this.elements.forEach(function(element) {
        element.reset();
      });

      this.draw();
    }
  };

  function WalkwayElement(el, duration, easing) {
    this.el = el;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.easing = easing;
    this.animationStart = null;
    this.animationStarted = false;
  }

  WalkwayElement.prototype = {
    constructor: WalkwayElement,

    /*
     * This contains the general update logic for all supported svg
     * elements.
     *
     * @returns {boolean} true if the animation is complete, false otherwise
     */
    update: function() {
      if (!this.animationStarted) {
        this.animationStart = Date.now();
        this.animationStarted = true;
      }

      var progress = this.easing((Date.now() - this.animationStart) / this.duration);

      this.fill(progress);

      return progress >= 1 ? true : false;
    },

    fill: function(progress) {
      var value = Math.ceil(this.length * (1 - progress));
      this.el.style.strokeDashoffset = value < 0 ? 0 : Math.abs(value);
    },

    complete: function() {
      this.fill(1);
    },

    reset: function() {
      this.done = false;
      this.animationStart = 0;
      this.animationStarted = false;
      this.fill(0);
    }
  };

  /*
   * Constructor for new path instance
   *
   * @param {node} path actual dom node of the path
   * @param {string} duration how long the animation should take to complete
   * @param {string} easing the type of easing used - default is easeInOutCubic.
   * @returns {Path}
   */

  function Path(path, duration, easing) {
    WalkwayElement.call(this, path, duration, easing);

    this.length = path.getTotalLength();
  }

  /*
   * Constructor for new Line instance
   *
   * @param {node} line actual dom node of the path
   * @param {string} duration how long the animation should take to complete
   * @param {string} easing the type of easing used - default is easeInOutCubic.
   * @returns {line}
   */

  function Line(line, duration, easing) {
    WalkwayElement.call(this, line, duration, easing);

    this.length = getLineLength(line);
  }

  /*
   * Constructor for new Polyline instance
   *
   * @param {node} polyline actual dom node of the path
   * @param {string} duration how long the animation should take to complete
   * @param {string} easing the type of easing used - default is easeInOutCubic.
   * @returns {polyline}
   */
  function Polyline(polyline, duration, easing) {
    WalkwayElement.call(this, polyline, duration, easing);

    this.length = getPolylineLength(polyline);
  }

  Path.prototype = Line.prototype = Polyline.prototype = Object.create(WalkwayElement.prototype);

  /*
   * Calculates the length of a polyline using pythagoras theorem for each line segment
   *
   * @param {node} polyline The polyline element to calculate length of
   * @returns {Number} Length of the polyline
   */

  function getPolylineLength(polyline) {
    var dist = 0;
    var x1, x2, y1, y2;
    var i;
    var points = polyline.points.numberOfItems;

    for (i = 1; i < points; i++){
      x1 = polyline.points.getItem(i - 1).x;
      x2 = polyline.points.getItem(i).x;
      y1 = polyline.points.getItem(i - 1).y;
      y2 = polyline.points.getItem(i).y;

      dist += Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    }

    return dist;
  }

  /*
   * Calculates the length a line using pythagoras theorem
   *
   * @param {node} line The line element to calculate length of
   * @returns {Number} Length of the line
   */

  function getLineLength(line) {
    var x1 = line.getAttribute('x1');
    var x2 = line.getAttribute('x2');
    var y1 = line.getAttribute('y1');
    var y2 = line.getAttribute('y2');

    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
  }

  return Walkway;
}));
```

```css
svg {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 fill: red;
 margin-left: 130px;
}

svg path {
 stroke: #310B3B;
}

svg:not(:root) {
 overflow: visible;
}

path {
 fill: transparent;
}

svg > span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}

path, line, polyline {
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1px;
}



polyline {
        stroke-width: 4px;
}

#Layer_1 path {
        stroke-width: 6.5px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Role para baixo
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M437.586,297.264c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267v56.517c0,9.597-7.807,17.405-17.405,17.405H212.561
   c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267c0,4.566,3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h0.552l-9.52,39.656c-0.591,2.462-0.021,5.059,1.547,7.048
   c1.567,1.988,3.96,3.149,6.492,3.149h111.689c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267c0-4.566-3.7-8.267-8.267-8.267h-32.429
   l-7.999-33.319h129.022c18.714,0,33.939-15.224,33.939-33.939v-56.517C445.853,300.966,442.153,297.264,437.586,297.264z
    M222.118,429.306l7.999-33.319h35.772l7.999,33.319H222.118z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M346.573,92.259H75.284c-18.72,0-33.95,15.23-33.95,33.95l0.001,78.903c0,4.566,3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267l-0.001-78.903c0-9.603,7.813-17.416,17.416-17.416h271.288c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267
   C354.84,95.961,351.139,92.259,346.573,92.259z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M413.746,344.236H210.357c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h203.389
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267S418.312,344.236,413.746,344.236z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M346.573,127.476H73.455c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267c0,4.566,3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h273.118
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267C354.84,131.178,351.139,127.476,346.573,127.476z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M503.733,203.388c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267v-127c0-14.314-11.644-25.959-25.959-25.959h-96.886
   c-14.314,0-25.959,11.645-25.959,25.959v195.646c0,14.314,11.644,25.959,25.959,25.959h96.886
   c14.314,0,25.959-11.645,25.959-25.959v-43.844c0-4.566-3.7-8.267-8.267-8.267s-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267v43.844
   c0,5.197-4.228,9.425-9.425,9.425h-96.886c-5.197,0-9.425-4.228-9.425-9.425V68.121c0-5.197,4.228-9.425,9.425-9.425h96.886
   c5.197,0,9.425,4.228,9.425,9.425v127.001C495.466,199.687,499.166,203.388,503.733,203.388z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M329.575,211.025l-20.532-20.532c-3.229-3.227-8.462-3.229-11.692,0c-3.228,3.229-3.228,8.463,0,11.692l6.42,6.42h-72.136
   c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h72.136l-6.42,6.42c-3.228,3.229-3.228,8.463,0,11.692
   c1.615,1.614,3.731,2.422,5.846,2.422c2.115,0,4.232-0.807,5.846-2.422l20.532-20.532
   C332.803,219.487,332.803,214.253,329.575,211.025z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M323.728,267.023h-72.136l6.42-6.42c3.229-3.229,3.229-8.463,0-11.692c-3.229-3.227-8.462-3.229-11.692,0l-20.533,20.532
   c-1.55,1.551-2.421,3.653-2.421,5.845s0.871,4.296,2.421,5.845l20.533,20.532c1.615,1.614,3.731,2.422,5.846,2.422
   c2.115,0,4.232-0.807,5.846-2.422c3.229-3.229,3.229-8.463,0-11.692l-6.42-6.42h72.136c4.566,0.002,8.266-3.699,8.266-8.265
   S328.295,267.023,323.728,267.023z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M480.126,86.909h-85.058c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h85.058c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267
   S484.693,86.909,480.126,86.909z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M480.126,228.444h-85.058c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h85.058
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267S484.693,228.444,480.126,228.444z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M167.863,222.275H25.959C11.644,222.275,0,233.921,0,248.233v49.213c0,4.566,3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267
   s8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267v-49.213c0-5.197,4.228-9.425,9.425-9.425h141.904c5.197,0,9.425,4.228,9.425,9.425v195.646
   c0,5.197-4.228,9.425-9.425,9.425H25.959c-5.197,0-9.425-4.228-9.425-9.425V322.983c0-4.566-3.7-8.267-8.267-8.267
   S0,318.418,0,322.983v120.896c0,14.314,11.644,25.959,25.959,25.959h141.904c14.314,0,25.959-11.645,25.959-25.959V248.233
   C193.823,233.921,182.177,222.275,167.863,222.275z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M163.834,267.023H29.987c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.701,8.267,8.267,8.267h133.847
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267S168.401,267.023,163.834,267.023z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M163.834,408.557H29.987c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267c0,4.566,3.701,8.267,8.267,8.267h133.847
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267C172.101,412.259,168.401,408.557,163.834,408.557z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <circle cx="437.597" cy="258.943" r="8.267"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <circle cx="96.911" cy="439.526" r="8.267"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

**Como eu faço para quando a animação se completar, as bordas do desenho serem retiradas e entrar uma imagem no lugar?** Eu tenho esta imagem em vetor, com fundo transparente, então ficaria de boa.

[image: foto]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insira o código abaixo onde é verificado que a animação foi finalizada (dentro do `if(allComplete){`):

```
if(!terminou){
   terminou = true;
   $("#nova").fadeIn();
   $("#Layer_1").fadeOut();
}
```

Foi preciso criar uma nova `div` `#desenho` para agrupar o `svg` e outra `div` `#nova` que será a `div` com o fundo `.png`. Fiz isso porque adicionar um fundo dinamicamente nestas condições usando `.fadeIn()` iria causar aquele "pisca" na transição.

Também criei um *flag* `terminou = false;` para impedir que o código seja executado mais de uma vez desnecessariamente no `scroll` após o término da animação.

```js
terminou = false;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

   var svg4 = new Walkway({
    selector: '#Layer_1',
    duration: 3500,
    redrawOnFocus: true
   });

   $(window).on("scroll", function(){
      var el = $('#Layer_1');
      var eleHeight = el.outerHeight(); // altura do elemento
      var eleTopo = el.offset().top; // distancia do elemento ao topo do documento
      var scrlTopo = $(window).scrollTop(); // quanto foi rolada a janela
      var distance = eleTopo-scrlTopo; // distancia do elemento ao topo da janela
      var altJanela = window.innerHeight; // altura da janela
      if(distance <= altJanela-(eleHeight/2)) {
         svg4.draw(); // inicia a animação
      }
   });

  document.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
    svg.redraw();
    svg4.redraw();
  }, false);
});

/*
 * Walkway.js
 *
 * Copyright 2016, Connor Atherton - http://connoratherton.com/
 * Released under the MIT Licence
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 * Github: http://github.com/ConnorAtherton/Walkway
 */

// Export Walkway depending on environment (AMD, CommonJS or Browser global)
;(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    root.Walkway = factory();
  }
}(this, function factory(exports) {
  'use strict';

  /*
   * Shim for requestAnimationFrame on older browsers
   */

  var lastTime = 0;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame;

  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
        callback(currTime + timeToCall);
      }, timeToCall);

      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };
  }

  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  }

  /*
   * Easing Functions - inspired from http://gizma.com/easing/
   * only considering the t value for the range [0, 1] => [0, 1]
   *
   * Taken from https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
   */

  var EasingFunctions = {
    // no easing, no acceleration
    linear: function (t) { return t; },
    // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInQuad: function (t) { return t*t; },
      // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutQuad: function (t) { return t*(2-t); },
      // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutQuad: function (t) { return t<0.5 ? 2*t*t : -1+(4-2*t)*t; },
      // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInCubic: function (t) { return t*t*t; },
      // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutCubic: function (t) { return (--t)*t*t+1; },
      // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutCubic: function (t) { return t<0.5 ? 4*t*t*t : (t-1)*(2*t-2)*(2*t-2)+1; },
      // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInQuart: function (t) { return t*t*t*t; },
      // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutQuart: function (t) { return 1-(--t)*t*t*t; },
      // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutQuart: function (t) { return t<0.5 ? 8*t*t*t*t : 1-8*(--t)*t*t*t; },
      // accelerating from zero velocity
    easeInQuint: function (t) { return t*t*t*t*t; },
      // decelerating to zero velocity
    easeOutQuint: function (t) { return 1+(--t)*t*t*t*t; },
      // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    easeInOutQuint: function (t) { return t<0.5 ? 16*t*t*t*t*t : 1+16*(--t)*t*t*t*t; }
  };

  /*
   * Creates a selector used to select all element to animate
   * Currently only supports *path*, *line*, and *polyline* svg elements
   *
   * @param {string} selector The selector of the parent element
   * @returns {string} the complete selector
   * @private
   */

  function _createSelector(selector) {
    var supported = ['path', 'line', 'polyline'];
    var newSelector = supported.reduce(function(prev, curr){
      return prev + selector + ' ' + curr + ', ';
    }, '');
    // chop the last , from the string
    return newSelector.slice(0, -2);
  }

  /*
   * All Walkway instances present on the current page. This is needed for when
   * the tab loses focus and we need to force each animation to finish.
   */
  var _elements = [];
  var _instances = [];

  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (!document.hidden) {
      return;
    }

    for (var i = 0, instancesLen = _instances.length; i < instancesLen; i++) {
      _instances[i].cancel();
    }

    for (var j = 0, elementsLen = _elements.length; j < elementsLen; j++) {
      _elements[j].complete();
    }
  }, false);

  /*
   * Walkway constructor function
   * opts.selector is the only mandatory param and can be passed in alone
   * as a string
   *
   * @param {object} opts the configuration objects for the instance.
   * @returns {walkway}
   */

  function Walkway(opts) {
    if (!(this instanceof Walkway)) {
      return new Walkway(opts);
    }

    if (typeof opts === 'string') {
      opts = { selector: opts };
    }

    if (!opts.selector) {
      return this.error('A selector needs to be specified');
    }

    this.opts = opts;
    this.selector = opts.selector;
    this.duration = opts.duration || 500;
    this.easing = (typeof opts.easing === 'function') ?
      opts.easing :
      EasingFunctions[opts.easing] || EasingFunctions.easeInOutCubic;
    this.id = false;
    this.elements = this.getElements();
    this.callback = opts.callback;

    this.setInitialStyles();

    _elements = _elements.concat(this.elements);
    _instances.push(this);
  }

  Walkway.prototype = {
    constructor: Walkway,

    /*
     * Prints an error message to the console
     *
     * @param {string} message the message to be displayed
     * @returns {void}
     */
    error: function(message) {
      console.error('Walkway error: ' + message);
    },

    /*
     * Uses a pre-build selector to find and store elements to animate
     *
     * @returns {array} of Path instances
     */
    getElements: function() {
      var self = this;
      var selector = _createSelector(this.selector);
      var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      els = Array.prototype.slice.call(els);

      return els.map(function(el) {
        if(el.tagName === 'path') {
          return new Path(el, self.duration, self.easing);
        } else if (el.tagName === 'line') {
          return new Line(el, self.duration, self.easing);
        } else if(el.tagName === 'polyline') {
          return new Polyline(el, self.duration, self.easing);
        }
      });
    },

    /*
     * Sets initial styles on all elements to be animated
     *
     * @returns {void}
     */
    setInitialStyles: function() {
      this.elements.forEach(function(n) {
        n.el.style.strokeDasharray = n.length + ' ' + n.length;
        n.el.style.strokeDashoffset = n.length;
      });
    },

    /*
     * The general update loop for the animations.
     * Once individal paths are completed they are marked as such and
     * are not updated.
     *
     * @returns {void}
     */
    draw: function(callback) {
      var counter = this.elements.length;
      var allComplete = this.elements.filter(function(el) { return el.done; }).length === counter;
      var element = null;
      var done = false;

      // Overwrite existing callback passed in with options
      this.callback = callback || this.callback;

      if (allComplete) {
        if (this.callback && typeof(this.callback) === 'function') {
          this.callback();
        }

         if(!terminou){
            terminou = true;
            $("#nova").fadeIn();
            $("#Layer_1").fadeOut();
         }

        this.cancel();
        return;
      }

      while (counter--) {
        element = this.elements[counter];
        done = element.update();

        if (done) {
          element.done = true;
        }
      }

      this.id = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this, callback));
    },

    cancel: function() {
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.id);
    },

    redraw: function() {
      this.cancel();

      this.elements.forEach(function(element) {
        element.reset();
      });

      this.draw();
    }
  };

  function WalkwayElement(el, duration, easing) {
    this.el = el;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.easing = easing;
    this.animationStart = null;
    this.animationStarted = false;
  }

  WalkwayElement.prototype = {
    constructor: WalkwayElement,

    /*
     * This contains the general update logic for all supported svg
     * elements.
     *
     * @returns {boolean} true if the animation is complete, false otherwise
     */
    update: function() {
      if (!this.animationStarted) {
        this.animationStart = Date.now();
        this.animationStarted = true;
      }

      var progress = this.easing((Date.now() - this.animationStart) / this.duration);

      this.fill(progress);

      return progress >= 1 ? true : false;
    },

    fill: function(progress) {
      var value = Math.ceil(this.length * (1 - progress));
      this.el.style.strokeDashoffset = value < 0 ? 0 : Math.abs(value);
    },

    complete: function() {
      this.fill(1);
    },

    reset: function() {
      this.done = false;
      this.animationStart = 0;
      this.animationStarted = false;
      this.fill(0);
    }
  };

  /*
   * Constructor for new path instance
   *
   * @param {node} path actual dom node of the path
   * @param {string} duration how long the animation should take to complete
   * @param {string} easing the type of easing used - default is easeInOutCubic.
   * @returns {Path}
   */

  function Path(path, duration, easing) {
    WalkwayElement.call(this, path, duration, easing);

    this.length = path.getTotalLength();
  }

  /*
   * Constructor for new Line instance
   *
   * @param {node} line actual dom node of the path
   * @param {string} duration how long the animation should take to complete
   * @param {string} easing the type of easing used - default is easeInOutCubic.
   * @returns {line}
   */

  function Line(line, duration, easing) {
    WalkwayElement.call(this, line, duration, easing);

    this.length = getLineLength(line);
  }

  /*
   * Constructor for new Polyline instance
   *
   * @param {node} polyline actual dom node of the path
   * @param {string} duration how long the animation should take to complete
   * @param {string} easing the type of easing used - default is easeInOutCubic.
   * @returns {polyline}
   */
  function Polyline(polyline, duration, easing) {
    WalkwayElement.call(this, polyline, duration, easing);

    this.length = getPolylineLength(polyline);
  }

  Path.prototype = Line.prototype = Polyline.prototype = Object.create(WalkwayElement.prototype);

  /*
   * Calculates the length of a polyline using pythagoras theorem for each line segment
   *
   * @param {node} polyline The polyline element to calculate length of
   * @returns {Number} Length of the polyline
   */

  function getPolylineLength(polyline) {
    var dist = 0;
    var x1, x2, y1, y2;
    var i;
    var points = polyline.points.numberOfItems;

    for (i = 1; i < points; i++){
      x1 = polyline.points.getItem(i - 1).x;
      x2 = polyline.points.getItem(i).x;
      y1 = polyline.points.getItem(i - 1).y;
      y2 = polyline.points.getItem(i).y;

      dist += Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    }

    return dist;
  }

  /*
   * Calculates the length a line using pythagoras theorem
   *
   * @param {node} line The line element to calculate length of
   * @returns {Number} Length of the line
   */

  function getLineLength(line) {
    var x1 = line.getAttribute('x1');
    var x2 = line.getAttribute('x2');
    var y1 = line.getAttribute('y1');
    var y2 = line.getAttribute('y2');

    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
  }

  return Walkway;
}));
```

```css
#desenho {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
   position: relative;
 margin-left: 130px;
}

#nova{
   display:none;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   background:url(http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/teste1.png);
}

svg{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 fill: red;
}

svg path {
 stroke: #310B3B;
}

svg:not(:root) {
 overflow: visible;
}

path {
 fill: transparent;
}

svg > span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}

path, line, polyline {
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1px;
}



polyline {
        stroke-width: 4px;
}

#Layer_1 path {
        stroke-width: 6.5px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Role para baixo
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<div id="desenho">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M437.586,297.264c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267v56.517c0,9.597-7.807,17.405-17.405,17.405H212.561
   c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267c0,4.566,3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h0.552l-9.52,39.656c-0.591,2.462-0.021,5.059,1.547,7.048
   c1.567,1.988,3.96,3.149,6.492,3.149h111.689c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267c0-4.566-3.7-8.267-8.267-8.267h-32.429
   l-7.999-33.319h129.022c18.714,0,33.939-15.224,33.939-33.939v-56.517C445.853,300.966,442.153,297.264,437.586,297.264z
    M222.118,429.306l7.999-33.319h35.772l7.999,33.319H222.118z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M346.573,92.259H75.284c-18.72,0-33.95,15.23-33.95,33.95l0.001,78.903c0,4.566,3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267l-0.001-78.903c0-9.603,7.813-17.416,17.416-17.416h271.288c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267
   C354.84,95.961,351.139,92.259,346.573,92.259z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M413.746,344.236H210.357c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h203.389
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267S418.312,344.236,413.746,344.236z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M346.573,127.476H73.455c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267c0,4.566,3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h273.118
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267C354.84,131.178,351.139,127.476,346.573,127.476z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M503.733,203.388c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267v-127c0-14.314-11.644-25.959-25.959-25.959h-96.886
   c-14.314,0-25.959,11.645-25.959,25.959v195.646c0,14.314,11.644,25.959,25.959,25.959h96.886
   c14.314,0,25.959-11.645,25.959-25.959v-43.844c0-4.566-3.7-8.267-8.267-8.267s-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267v43.844
   c0,5.197-4.228,9.425-9.425,9.425h-96.886c-5.197,0-9.425-4.228-9.425-9.425V68.121c0-5.197,4.228-9.425,9.425-9.425h96.886
   c5.197,0,9.425,4.228,9.425,9.425v127.001C495.466,199.687,499.166,203.388,503.733,203.388z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M329.575,211.025l-20.532-20.532c-3.229-3.227-8.462-3.229-11.692,0c-3.228,3.229-3.228,8.463,0,11.692l6.42,6.42h-72.136
   c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h72.136l-6.42,6.42c-3.228,3.229-3.228,8.463,0,11.692
   c1.615,1.614,3.731,2.422,5.846,2.422c2.115,0,4.232-0.807,5.846-2.422l20.532-20.532
   C332.803,219.487,332.803,214.253,329.575,211.025z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M323.728,267.023h-72.136l6.42-6.42c3.229-3.229,3.229-8.463,0-11.692c-3.229-3.227-8.462-3.229-11.692,0l-20.533,20.532
   c-1.55,1.551-2.421,3.653-2.421,5.845s0.871,4.296,2.421,5.845l20.533,20.532c1.615,1.614,3.731,2.422,5.846,2.422
   c2.115,0,4.232-0.807,5.846-2.422c3.229-3.229,3.229-8.463,0-11.692l-6.42-6.42h72.136c4.566,0.002,8.266-3.699,8.266-8.265
   S328.295,267.023,323.728,267.023z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M480.126,86.909h-85.058c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h85.058c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267
   S484.693,86.909,480.126,86.909z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M480.126,228.444h-85.058c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267h85.058
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267S484.693,228.444,480.126,228.444z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M167.863,222.275H25.959C11.644,222.275,0,233.921,0,248.233v49.213c0,4.566,3.7,8.267,8.267,8.267
   s8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267v-49.213c0-5.197,4.228-9.425,9.425-9.425h141.904c5.197,0,9.425,4.228,9.425,9.425v195.646
   c0,5.197-4.228,9.425-9.425,9.425H25.959c-5.197,0-9.425-4.228-9.425-9.425V322.983c0-4.566-3.7-8.267-8.267-8.267
   S0,318.418,0,322.983v120.896c0,14.314,11.644,25.959,25.959,25.959h141.904c14.314,0,25.959-11.645,25.959-25.959V248.233
   C193.823,233.921,182.177,222.275,167.863,222.275z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M163.834,267.023H29.987c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267s3.701,8.267,8.267,8.267h133.847
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267S168.401,267.023,163.834,267.023z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="M163.834,408.557H29.987c-4.567,0-8.267,3.701-8.267,8.267c0,4.566,3.701,8.267,8.267,8.267h133.847
   c4.567,0,8.267-3.701,8.267-8.267C172.101,412.259,168.401,408.557,163.834,408.557z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <circle cx="437.597" cy="258.943" r="8.267"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <circle cx="96.911" cy="439.526" r="8.267"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
   <div id="nova"></div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: tem como fazer essa troca de imagem com um efeito fade? pra nao "piscar" e sim ir perdendo a opacidade até trocar de foto.

Comment: ok, obrigado! eu tinha falado contigo no whatsapp tbm, então ignore a mensagem lá kkk, já que vc me ajudou aqui :D

Comment: tire só uma outra duvida minha por favor, (quando vc acabar de fazer o efeito fade), no caso da sua resposta sua imagem foi inserida pelo JS mesmo, por uma url, como faço para inserir a imagem que vai estar lá na minha pasta img?

Comment: definitivamente perfeito, sempre vejo vc respondendo varias perguntas aqui no site, muito inteligente... inspiração real.
obrigado

Comment: @LukasMonteiro Valeu, obg! A gente faz o que pode. Obg!